# Query won't match on email address

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have the following query that works fine in SSMS:

```
SELECT ClientID FROM xxx.ClientUsers WHERE UserName = 'user@email.com'
```

It will return a single integer value for ClientID (ClientID and UserName are the PK).

If I try the same query in a controller and it fails to return results. I have confirmed that `User.Identity.Name` exists in the table. Even with a hardcoded email address it will not return data.

```
var iTemp = -1;
iTemp = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(@"SELECT ClientID FROM xxx.ClientUsers WHERE 
UserName = '" + User.Identity.Name + "'").First();
```

The code above returns no rows.

Comment: `User.Identity.Name` contains email or just Name ?

Comment: Are you using entity framework?

Comment: What site is this?  I want my friend, `Jimmy'); DROP TABLE ClientUsers; --` to sign up!

Comment: User.Identity.Name is an email address (using the default authentication). Also using entity framework.

Comment: sql injection prone. drop that jimmy! hehe

Comment: Are you absolutely 100% sure that SSMS and ASP.NET are *actually* talking to the same database?  I know I've *intended* that SSMS and my code operate against the same database before, but then I forgot to update a connection string or found I was executing against the live db instead of dev.

Comment: If you breakpoint on your `SqlQuery` line you can inspect `db.Database.ConnectionString`.

Comment: Yes, only one connection string. I just updated data in database and confirmed that it reflected in the app. Plus I can select and loop through data just fine, once I add the where it doesn't return results.

Comment: MVC is not a database access framework.  Because you are using `Database.SqlQuery<>` I am pretty sure you're using [tag:entity-framework].

Comment: Is your code executing correctly? Are you by chance wrapping your code in a try-catch and suppressing any errors? If you haven't, I agree that setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code is a good starting place.

Comment: Using entity framework.

Comment: I can select without a where clause and loop through results and see the email I want. When I add the where clause it no longer returns results. Even though exact same query works fine elsewhere.

Comment: Could the value in the database have any trailing (or preceding) spaces, tabs, etc?

Comment: Did you debugged or printed the value of `User.Identity.Name` ? Is that the same e-mail address? Is everything in lowercase?

Comment: If you have admin access to the database server, you might be able to run a trace to verify what's actually being executed. Assuming you're using SQL Server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler

Answer (score 1):

If you are using raw sql query with entity framework, make sure to use proper parametrization and avoid being vulnerable to SQL injections:

```
var iTemp = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    @"SELECT ClientID FROM xxx.ClientUsers WHERE UserName = @UserName", 
    new SqlParameter("UserName", User.Identity.Name)).FirstOrDefault();
```

or even better, you can use LINQ:

```
var result = db.ClientUsers.Where(x => x.UserName == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault(); 
if(result != null)
{
    var clientId = result.ClientID;
}
```

Comment: That LINQ query is going to blow up if no rows are returned. You need to use `.FirstOrDefault()` and assign it to a variable. Then, if it's not null, you can get `.ClientID`.

Comment: You don't need both `Where([query]).FirstOrDefault();`; you can just do `FirstOrDefault([query]);`.

Answer (score 0):

Code from a now deleted answer works after exiting and reloading the project. Not sure what was happening, or what I might have done? Anyhow, thank you everyone for your help! At the very least I learned a better way to execute the query.

```
var result = db.ClientUsers.Where(x => x.UserName == User.Identity.Name).First().ClientID;
```

Comment: I brought back the answer that you say it helped you. It was deleted because you initially reported it didn't work for you.

Comment: This is going to blow up if no rows are returned. You need to use `.FirstOrDefault()` and assign it to a variable. Then, if it's not null, you can get `.ClientID`.